# reverse dns not propagated

Tags: reverse-dns, ptr-record

I defined reverse dns zone for server `muq.ac.ir` in name server which responds to name resolutions for domain `muq.ac.ir` server. Then I add a ptr record for ip address `80.191.92.199` with value `muq.ac.ir`. however after around 12 hours I still could not reverse-lookup my domain.

 Did i missed something about dns server or my server is not responsible for reverse lookups?

 Or still dns server not propagated?

Comment: The DNS server for the `muq.ac.ir` domain name is not responsible for the rDNS zone for the ip address 80.191.92.199. You need to have the entity that is responsible for that ip address create the PTR record for you.

Comment: How can i have that or who have that? Since I'm not expert at dns,I don't know who should set it.

Comment: Looks like you need to talk with the network group at the Medical university of qom.

Comment: I did query domain 80.191.92.199 in dns server of .ir domain using nic.ir however it respond: No Name Server has been defined in IRNIC DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DNS server is not responsible for this zone. You can check it with dig request:

```
$ dig 92.191.80.in-addr.arpa 

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> 92.191.80.in-addr.arpa
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 63048
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;92.191.80.in-addr.arpa.        IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
80.in-addr.arpa.    3463    IN  SOA pri.authdns.ripe.net. dns.ripe.net. 1409314932 3600 600 864000 7200

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.254#53(192.168.0.254)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 31 23:33:08 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

Public addresses are provided from RIPE and they are delegating addresses to others company. If you are not owner of this block of IP addresses then you should ask to create PTR company which provided this public IP to you. In general it's internet service or hosting providers.

Here is information about owner of this ip addresses block and BGP AS number for this block:

```
$ whois 80.191.92.199
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '80.191.92.192 - 80.191.92.255'

% Abuse contact for '80.191.92.192 - 80.191.92.255' is 'R.javidi@tci.ir'

inetnum:        80.191.92.192 - 80.191.92.255
netname:        MEDUNIQOM
descr:          Medical university of qom
country:        IR
admin-c:        KS3649-RIPE
tech-c:         KS3649-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         AS12880-MNT
source:         RIPE # Filtered

person:         Kayyal Saied
address:        Saheli St.,Qom,Iran
phone:          +98 251 772 36 60
nic-hdl:        KS3649-RIPE
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '80.191.64.0/19As12880'

route:          80.191.64.0/19
descr:          DCI-Route
origin:         As12880
mnt-by:         AS12880-MNT
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.75 (DB-3)
```

Comment: does this dig command have equivalent in windows?

Comment: sure you can run nslookup 92.191.80.in-addr.arpa. Most important things here is top domain "in-addr.arpa" and that ip addresses in this domain are reversed. So if you have IP 80.191.92.199 than PTR record will be(if you use bind syntax):

199.92.191.80.in-addr.arpa IN PTR muq.ac.ir

Comment: Look how ANSWER section looks for google.com IP:
`$ dig -x 216.239.38.10

;; ANSWER SECTION:

10.38.239.216.in-addr.arpa. 86330 IN PTR ns4.google.com.
`